# LoginHandler with ldapjs and Meteor.methods

Tags: meteor, ldap

I try to implement a logIn in Meteor 0.9.2.1 with LDAPJS and Meteor methods. The code for the server-side is:

```
var Future = Meteor.npmRequire('fibers/future');
var ldap = Meteor.npmRequire('ldapjs');

LDAP = {};
LDAP.ldap = ldap;

LDAP.serverIP = 'xxx';
LDAP.serverPort = 'xxx';
LDAP.searchOu = 'ou=xxx,dc=xxx,dc=xxx';
LDAP.searchQuery = function(user) {
    return{
        filter: '(uid=username)',
        scope: 'sub'
    }
};

LDAP.checkAccount = function (options) {        
    LDAP.client = ldap.createClient({
        url: 'ldap://' + LDAP.serverIP + ':' + LDAP.serverPort
    });

    options = options || {};
    var dn = [];
    future = new Future;

    if (options.hasOwnProperty('username') && options.hasOwnProperty('password')) {    
        LDAP.client.search(LDAP.searchOu, LDAP.searchQuery(options.username), function (err, search) {

            search.on('searchEntry', function(entry){
                //console.log('entry: ' + JSON.stringify(entry.object));
                dn.push(entry.object.uid);
                dn.push(entry.object.userPassword)
            });

            search.on('error', function (err) {
                throw new Meteor.Error(500, "LDAP server error");
            });

            search.on('end', function () {
                if (dn.length === 0) {
                    future['return'](false);
                    return false;
                }

                var testBind = LDAP.ldap.createClient({
                    url: 'ldap://' + LDAP.serverIP + ':' + LDAP.serverPort
                });

                testBind.bind(dn[10], options.password, function (err) {
                    future['return'](!err);
                });
                client.unbind(function (err) {
                    assert.ifError(err);
                    future['return'](!err);
                });
            });
        });
    } else {
        throw new Meteor.Error(400, "Missing Parameter");
    }
};

var loginHandler =  function (username, password) {
    Accounts.registerLoginHandler("ldapjs",function(loginRequest) {
        if (LDAP.checkAccount(loginRequest)) {
            var user = Meteor.users.findOne({ username: loginRequest.username });
            if(err){
                console.log(err)
            }    
            return {
                userId: uid    
            }
        }
    });
};

Meteor.methods({
   setSignIn: function(username, password) {  
       loginHandler(username,password)
    }
});
```

My Problem is, that when I want to log in it starts with the loginHandler. But than the console throws back that `Object has no method checkAccount`. I changed today a lot and I'm already totally confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got to work it. Referneces:
http://notjoshmiller.com/using-ldaps-in-meteor/, https://github.com/emgee3/meteor-accounts-ldap

server-side:

```
var Future = Meteor.npmRequire('fibers/future');
var ldap = Meteor.npmRequire('ldapjs');

var LDAP = {};
LDAP.ldap = ldap;

//provides the variables, needed for the connection
LDAP.serverIP = 'xxx';
LDAP.serverPort = 'xxx';
LDAP.searchOu = 'ou=xxx,dc=xxx,dc=xxx';
//is needed for the searchQuery, which delivers the Filter so that only the uid with 
//the given username get searched
LDAP.searchQuery = function(username) {
    return{
        filter: '(uid=' + username + ')',
        scope: 'sub'
    }
};

LDAP.checkAccount = function (options) {
    //connects the client, nginx is here not necessary
    LDAP.client = ldap.createClient({
        url: 'ldap://' + LDAP.serverIP + ':' + LDAP.serverPort
    });

    options = options || {};
    var dn = [];
    future = new Future;

    if (options.hasOwnProperty('username') && options.hasOwnProperty('password')) {
        //create the connection
        LDAP.client.search(LDAP.searchOu, LDAP.searchQuery(options.username), function (err, search) {
            if(err){
                console.log(err)
            }

            //uses the class searchEntry, which is node-specific
            search.on('searchEntry', function (entry) {
                dn.push(entry.objectName);
                LDAP.displayName = entry.object.displayName
                });    

            search.on('error', function (err) {
                throw new Meteor.Error(500, "LDAP server error");
            });

            //uses the end class to 'fulfill' the connection by binding
            search.on('end', function () {
                if (dn.length === 0) {
                    future['return'](false);
                    return false;
                }    

                LDAP.client.bind(dn[0], options.password, function (err) {
                    future['return'](!err);
                });
            });
        });

        return future.wait();
    } else {
        throw new Meteor.Error(400, "Missing Parameter");
    }
};

Meteor.startup(function(){   
    Accounts.registerLoginHandler("ldapjs", function (loginRequest) {
        if (LDAP.checkAccount(loginRequest)) {

            var userId;
            var user = Meteor.users.findOne({
                username : loginRequest.username
                //'profile.name': LDAP.displayName
            });

            if (user) {
                userId = user._id;

            } else {
                // If no Meteor Account is found for a valid LDAP logon,
                // you can either prevent logon by passing 'undefined' or
                // you can automatically create the new account.
                // return undefined;
                userId = Meteor.users.insert({ username : loginRequest.username });
            }

            return {
                userId: userId
            }
        }
        return undefined;
    });
});
```

client side:

```
Meteor.ldapLogin = function (username, password, callback) {
    var loginRequest = {
        username: username,
        password: password
    };
    Accounts.callLoginMethod({
        methodArguments: [loginRequest],
        userCallback: function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                Session.set('alert', 'No valid inputs!');
            } else {
                Router.go('/Home');
            }
        }
    });
};

//handles LogIn-Button, by using LDAPJS
Template.signIn.events({
    "submit #box-login": function (e, t) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var signInForm = $(e.currentTarget),
            username = trimInput(signInForm.find('#emailSignIn').val().toLowerCase()),
            password = signInForm.find('#passwordSignIn').val();

        if(isNotEmpty(username)&& isNotEmpty(password)) {
                Meteor.ldapLogin(username, password, function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err)
                        Session.set('alert', 'Sorry, something went wrong.');
                    }
                });    
        } else {
            Session.set('alert','Please insert your username and password!')
        }    
        return false;
    }
});
```

PS: No Meteor.methods and Meteor.call is needed! It might change with every new Meteor version and package, but I guess u're aware of that ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate the empty object as `var LDAP = {}`. Rest will be solved magically :)

Comment: it shows not the object error anymore but now, pretty strange: 1. cliuck it starts with the login and checkAccount, but then nothing. 2. Click, it runs both of them twice and console throws : `Future resolved more than once`. I think there is something wrong with my Meteor.methods

Comment: after a lot of tests, it seems like my dn.length= 0

Comment: I think I found it out, I had to change a lot of small thinks and there are still a few mistakes, but I'll post the whole solution as soon as it is working